# How I secure my Vue.js routing when I work with an API and JWTs token?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, adonis.js, jwt

I’m building an app with Adonis.js for the API and Vue.js for the front-end. I’m using JWT token to secure all routes of my API.

I understand the power of JWT to secure routes of API. When user create an account, a token is created to identified the user.

When I call my API from Vue I write the token of the active user in the header, and in my API I verify if the token is « active » and if is attributed on a user account ( and after that a make call to my databases..).

But the problem is (for me) I don’t understand how I can make a middleware to my vue route (verify if a user is authentify). I’have read some tutorial about that, and the conclusion is => store the token in local storage (ok, it’s logical) and make a middleware just checking if token exist.

But in my opinions this option is very not secure, because I can « enter » in my routes if I create a token manually in the local storage..

I’m very confusing about this concept.. can you open my eyes ehe ? 
Thanks

Comment: You can't protect anything in the client side. There should not be anything in your front-end code that's sensitive. A user who fakes their JWT can get to your front-end route, but that JWT should still be sent to the back-end to authorize access to the actual *data*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yeah, you were right that you should be using Vuex to store the value for the token to retrieve it using `getters` in your components/middleware. Your `state` would look something like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
    api_token: localStorage.getItem("api_token")
});
```

And `getters` would look something like this:

```
export const getters = {
    apiToken(state) {
        return state.api_token;
    }
}
```

To protect routes in the front-end you would be using router guard functions (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html). To give you an idea, this is what a simple check would look like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!store.getters["auth/apiToken"]) next('/login');
  else next();
})
```

Good luck!